# database stuck in restore

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I use sql server manager to restore a database called "surveytest" (destination db) from a database called "survey" (source db), when I do that the "surveytest" database is restored as it should but it also put the "survey" database in restoring mode, and its stuck there until I run ..

```
RESTORE DATABASE [survey] WITH RECOVERY
```

Can anyone see why this occurs? The code below is the generated code from sql server manager.

```
USE [master]

BACKUP LOG [Survey] 
    TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Survey_LogBackup_2015-01-04_10-36-04.bak' 
 WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
 NAME = N'Survey_LogBackup_2015-01-04_10-36-04', NOSKIP, NOREWIND, 
 NOUNLOAD,  NORECOVERY ,  STATS = 5


RESTORE DATABASE [SurveyTest] 
    FROM  DISK = N'D:\Work-Projects\Survey.2\Survey.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'Survey' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SurveyTest.mdf',  
MOVE N'Survey_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SurveyTest_log.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
GO
```

Comment: Any errors? Post the full text output.

Comment: No errors, its just the thing that database "Survey" get stuck in restoring, and I dont get why since I'm not restoring that one..

Comment: You are backing up the log with NORECOVERY. That puts the Survey DB into that state.

Comment: That script is generated from Sql Server manager, is the backup part really neccessary since I try to restore?

Comment: Well, for one you are backing up the wrong database. Apparently, you can just delete the backup operation and get what you want.

Comment: I have no idea of why Sql server manager generate the backup part when I do a restore operation, but as you suggest just delete the backup part works fine, the database is restored without the source database get stuck in restoring state. Thanks!

Comment: That's a so called tail log backup. It makes sure you don't loose a single transaction before overwriting the DB.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out, I did not know that :)